# Align href button and an image button in a single line

Tags: html, css, href

I have the following 2 buttons defined in html inside a `div` as:

```
<div class="button-div" align="center">

            <a id="cancel" style="background-color: #4b82c3;color: white;display:inline;text-decoration: none !important; font-size: 12px; padding: 10px 11px;margin: 8px 0;border: 1px;border-radius: 20px;" href="/">Cancel</a>

            <input type="image" id="btn" src="/static/images/submit-button.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit" width="90" height="40">

          </div>
```

Somehow, the button created using the `a tag` is not aligned with the button defined as an image. How do I align these buttons together?

PS: I don't face the issue if both the buttons are defined as an image.

Comment: `align="center"` has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `display:flex` with `flex-direction: row`:

```
<div class="button-div foo" align="center">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the css flex property to align your elements in a single line.